# How can i access Ms-Access database using MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2007

I want to access MS-ACCESS database using MYSQL query. I want to download some data from MS-ACCESS database table  to MYSQL table. But i have no idea to transfer the data from different databases. Please help me to find the solution..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**SQLyog's**](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) **Import External Data Feature** to import data from different data sources to MySQL (including MS-ACCESS).

You can go through [SQLyog's Help Documentation here](http://www.webyog.com/doc/SQLyog/#Migration_Toolkit_-_Select_File_or_Folder_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. MySQL cannot talk to MS Access. But you can, however, use MS Access to talk to MySQL, if an ODBC data source has been set up pointing at a database stored in MySQL.

You could then use Access itself to do the copying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Please give me some guidance,if any possible way transfer the MS Access data to MySQL.